# Defining gam function type

Tags: r, gam

I would like to apply a gam model on a dataset with specifying the types of functions to use.

It would be something like :
`y ~ cst1 * (s(var1)-s(var2)) * (1 - exp(var3*cst2))`

`s` has to be the same function for both `var1` and `var2`. I don't have a prior idea on `s` function family. If I resume, the model would find the constants (`cst1` and `cst2`) plus the function `s`.

Is it possible? If not, is there any way (another type of models) i can use to do what i'm looking for?

Thanks in advance for replies.

Comment: var1 and var2 are one of the explicative variables and cst1, cst2 are multiplicative constants (numbers if you want). My dataset has 4 columns y, var1, var2 and var3 where y is the target.

Comment: Normally in a GAM the `s()` expands to a set of *linear* basis functions for your model, which serve the purpose of creating a flexible, smooth, but *not* technically nonlinear function of the predictor.  If you want to combine these with multiplicative terms you may be getting into difficult waters.

Comment: I see... what should i use then?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You may be able to use the linear basis functions around the difference of var1 and var2 i.e. `s(var1-var2)`. On another matter, you don't need to specify the model parameterization (e.g. the exp() term) with GAM, that is the point of the non-linear basis functions. Does `gam(y ~ s(var1) + s(var2), ...)` not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This model could be fit with `nls`, the non-linear least squares package. This will allow you to model the formula you want directly. The splines will need to be done manually, though. [This question gets at what you would be trying to do.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139242/splines-inside-nonlinear-least-squares-in-r)

As far as getting the splines to be the same for `var1` and `var2`, you can do this by subtracting the basis matrices. Basically you want to compute the coefficient vector `A` where the term is `A * s(var1) + A * s(var2) = A * (s(var1) - s(var2))`. You wouldn't want to just do `s(var1 - var2)`; in general, `f(x) - f(y) != f(x - y)`. To do this in R, you would

1. Compute the spline basis matrices with `ns()` for `var1` and `var2`, *giving them the same knots*. You need to specify both the `knots` and the `Boundary.knots` parameters so that the two splines will share the same basis.
2. Subtract the two spline basis matrices (the output from the `ns()` function).
3. Adapt the resulting subtracted spline basis matrix for the `nls` formula, as they do in the question I linked earlier.

Comment: really helpful. I'm going to try this, but it already seems to answer my question. Thanks a lot.